# How to display some special symbols in jasper report using iReport designer?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working on jasper reports. I have crystal reports with me and I am creating jasper reports for available crystal reports.

In one of the crystal reports, I came across some symbols as shown in the following image:

[image: image for special symbol]

In crystal report, variable is created to display these symbols with some expression as:

```
char(254)
char(111)
```

I am not getting a way to do the same in iReport. Can someone suggest any way for this?

Answer (score 0):

We achieved it with the help of images. It also enabled us to change the images on certain conditions.

```
<image>
<imageExpression class="java.lang.String">
  <![CDATA[$P{mydir} + "/img/mylogo.jpg"]]>
</imageExpression>
</image>
```

Comment: i don't want to show image. I want to convert ascii value of char into char

Answer (score 0):

You can use html entities.For eg,if you want to show degree sign,use html entity-"ampersand deg semicolon"(use symbols-& for ampersand,; for semicolon)-"°"Set a static text-text property to ° and Markup property to html.